# Facebook like button for a facebook status

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I've pulled some facebook statusses to my website and I would like to add a like-button to them. I can't seem to use the facebook like button generator. When trowing a url like this:
http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=268577716517595&id=224519707563955 in the facebook url linter tool it sais it can't crawl itself.

Is there a way to fix this like-button? A way of custom coding a facebook like button? or is the only solution to redirect to this url?(Not an great option, i want the user to stay on my website)

I hope anybody has a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform an like of an object through the Graph API, but then the user have to authenticate your application.

See more under the like section [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Comment: Thx! Luckily there's stack overflow for these things. I think FB's documentation is badly written, they should make it more comprehensive like the flickr or twitter api