# Jquery trigger click on facebook like button by clicking on another button

Tags: jquery, button, triggers, facebook-like

Hi i'm using html5 facebook like button, i would like to trigger the click on that clicking on another styled button, is it possible?

Me i tryed this with no results:

```
<div class="row-fluid centered-content">
              <div class="hide">

                <div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" data-send="false" data-width="1" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
              </div>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="$('.fb-like').trigger('click');" rel="tooltipRIGHT" data-original-title="Share on facebook"><img src="<?php echo base_static_url();?>img/icons/facebook.png" width="24" height="24"/></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: There is no click handlers for `fb-like` div.

Comment: @gdoron and how to use custom button to share on fb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldnt be possible cause of security reasons.

If you could delegate clicks to facebook or twitter like buttons, you wouldnt need any permission from the user to do so...

[other answers to issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277449/how-to-trigger-facebook-like-from-an-image-map?rq=1)